# child process failed, exited with error number 4 mongodb

Tags: mongodb

first I want to restore the database mongodb manner, copy the file folder / var / lib / mongo and after I copy the file and I tried with mongo --repair ago I tried to "service mongod start" and this error occurred

```
 Starting mongod: about to fork child process, waiting until server is
 ready for                                                             
 connections. forked process: 25856 all output going to:
 /var/log/mongo/mongod.log ERROR: child process failed, exited with
 error number 4
                                                            [FAILED]
```

Last I checked there was an error in the log mongo

```
MongoDB starting : pid=25622 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=1.example.com
db version v2.4.14
allocator: tcmalloc
options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongo", fork: "true", journal: "/var/lib/mongo/journal", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongo/mongod.log", pidfilepath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }

** WARNING: Readahead for /var/lib/mongo is set to 2048KB
**          We suggest setting it to 256KB (512 sectors) or less
**          http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead
journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
****
****
need to upgrade database admin with pdfile version 4.21, new version: 4.5
     Not upgrading, exiting
     run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again
****
dbexit: 
shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
shutdown: going to close sockets...
shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
shutdown: lock for final commit...
shutdown: final commit...
shutdown: closing all files...
closeAllFiles() finished
journalCleanup...
removeJournalFiles
shutdown: removing fs lock...
really exiting now
```

anyone can help me for this problem? :) Thanks before, sorry if my bad english

Comment: `run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again` Did you run `--upgrade` ?

Comment: yes I've tried to run "mongod --upgrade" but still appear error
________________________________________________________

 need to upgrade database admin with pdfile version 4.21, new version: 4.5
   Not upgrading, exiting
   run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again
 ****
dbexit: 
 shutdown: going to close listening sockets
 shutdown: going to flush diaglog
 shutdown: going to close sockets
 shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator
 shutdown: lock for final commit